# Apply /statistics topic without rqt gui

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there,
I want to collect statistics on the ROS system. I noticed the topic '/statistics' which is available when I apply rqt gui.
Someone knows if there is a way to apply /statistics topic without rqt gui (rqt_graphprofiler plugin)?

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270470/apply-/statistics-topic-without-rqt-gui/) by [matansar](https://answers.ros.org/users/29912/matansar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2017-09-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `statistics` topic is a topic, the rqt gui just provides a convenient way to visualise the contents.

You should be able to access the same data by subscribing to the topic.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1